# Do you know any video tutorials focused purely on Closures in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, closures

I am having a problem to really get the point when it comes to 'closures' in JavaScript.

Do you know any video tutorials focused purely on defining closures in JavaScript with simple and clear examples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

Stuart Langridge: Secrets of JavaScript Closures:
http://vimeo.com/1967261

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly for JavaScript and closures, but for functional programming if you have problems to accept the concept of functions as values. 
A basic introduction:

http://academicearth.org/lectures/functional-programming-i